# (Why) Can I not throw an exception out of a generator?

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6, throw, babeljs

I'm trying to throw an exception from the body of an ES6 generator function, but it's not going through. Is this part of the ES6 specification or a quirk of Babel?

Here is the code I tried ([on babeljs.io](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&playground=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20*gen()%20%7B%0A%20%20throw%20new%20Error('x')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atry%20%7B%0A%20%20gen()%3B%0A%20%20console.log('not%20throwing')%3B%0A%7D%20catch(e)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log('throwing')%3B%0A%7D%0A)):

```
function *gen() {
    throw new Error('x');
}

try {
    gen();
    console.log('not throwing');
} catch(e) {
    console.log('throwing');
}
```

If this is indeed specified ES6 behavior, what's an alternative approach for signalling an exception?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You created an iterator but didn't run it.

```
var g = gen();
g.next(); // throws 'x'
```

([on babel repl](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&playground=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20*gen()%20%7B%0A%20%20throw%20new%20Error('x')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atry%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20g%20%3D%20gen()%3B%0A%20%20g.next()%3B%0A%20%20console.log('not%20throwing')%3B%0A%7D%20catch(e)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log('throwing')%3B%0A%7D%0A))

Here's another example:

```
function *gen() {
    for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
        yield i;
        if (i >= 5)
            throw new Error('x');
    }
}

try {
    for (n of gen())
        console.log(n); // will throw after `5`
    console.log('not throwing');
} catch(e) {
    console.log('throwing', e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, in retrospect. If I want to throw an exception before `.next()` is called, I'll have to create a normal function to wrap the generator function.

Comment: What would be useful would be to throw a `StopIteration`.